# Emacs plugin to list all methods in a python module

Tags: python, emacs

Is there a emacs plugin which lists all the methods in the module in a side pane.

I am looking for a plugin which has keyboard shortcuts to show/hide all the methods in python module file currently opened.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest using [elpy](https://elpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html#overview).

`C-c C-o` runs elpy-occur-definitions which creates a new buffer with a list of all the class and function signatures.

You can navigate the list using `C-n` and `C-p`. 
The mode works with next-error-follow minor mode.
So `C-c C-f` inside the buffer enables jumping to the class or function definition selected.

Here's an example of the contents of that buffer:

```
8 matches for "^ *\(def\|class\) " in buffer: leveling_utils.py
 11:def leveling(episodes_with_potential_associations_by_member):
 26:def _apply_leveling(sorted_episodes):
 41:def _set_non_chronic_associations(episode):
 73:def _apply_sub_to_procedural_association(assoc):
 94:def _set_chronic_associations(episode):
102:def _set_associations_for_self(episode):
118:def _set_to_actual(association):
122:def _log_actual_associations(member, leveled_episodes):
```

By the way, it has many other useful features that to me, make it a necessary addition to python-mode.

Comment: When doing `C-c C-o`, how can I make it to *not* use an already open buffer, instead open a new one?

Comment: helm-occur would be a general replacement for elpy-occur-definitions. It use helm as bottom pane, then type the keyword(e.g. def) and use TAB to jump to selected item.

Answer (score 3):

For the first question, use <kbd>M-x</kbd>`speed-bar`, like Alex suggested.

For the second, enable `hs-minor-mode`, <kbd>M-x</kbd>`hs-minor-mode`, and use <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-@</kbd><kbd>C-S-h</kbd> to hide all methods, and <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-@</kbd><kbd>C-S-s</kbd> to show.

Comment: There isn't a "first" and a "second" question. The second sentence in the OP's question explains in more detail what the first sentence means.

Comment: First sentence asks to "list". The second asks to "show/hide". Different questions, although related.

Answer (score 2):

You can look to [ECB](http://ecb.sf.net/) (it's better to take [my fork](https://github.com/alexott/ecb) of it, as it's adapted to fresh Emacs & CEDET) - it can display information about source code fetching it from Semantic (CEDET subpackage) or via `imenu` (for languages that aren't supported by Semantic).

Speedbar (included into GNU Emacs) can also show a list of top level objects, but doesn't show differences between imports, functions of other top-level stuff

Answer (score 2):

For me, the easiest and most convenient method to quickly lookup methods is the command helm-occur (C-x c M-s o). You start typing the name of the method you want to jump to and suggestions start popping in as you type. Then you hit enter to select the one you want and your cursor jumps right there in the code. Helm-occur wasn't strictly written for this purpose, but works quite well that way.

Answer (score 0):

Speedbar is good, and another nice alternative is helm-imenu. I've bind several keys to access it quicky from different contexts and use it most of the time